# capistrano callbacks not being invoked

Tags: capistrano

Just started using capistrano with railsless-deploy for a simple dev->production Wordpress site a couple of days ago and I'm really taken with it, but I'm running into a problem getting callbacks to work. Everything else works great, I can even call the tasks referenced by the callbacks directly. It doesn't even seem to matter where I put my before or after calls -- beginning of deploy.rb, end, middle, whatever. cap runs merrily along, just never invokes before or after. What am I doing wrong?

My deploy.rb is here: https://gist.github.com/jbfink/5263869 . I'm running it in rvm in a Vagrant VM. I've tried it with both Ruby 2.0 and 1.9.3 in rvm, same results.

Answer (score 0):

Relieved to report this isn't just me: using any hooks that depend on :symlink (or, apparently, :create_symlink) seem to fail silently -- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/164 . What a mess.